# How can I disable the editing of a column only when it contains a specific value?

Tags: primefaces

I am working on datatable in primefaces.I have the cells in edit mode currently. I want to disable the edit of cells which contain some specific value. I need to do that in just one of the columns. E.g, if the column contains number 1 to 10. I want the cell to be editable only when it does not contain the value '1'.

Comment: You can use rendered as I mention in my answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840393/how-to-make-a-primefaces-datatable-column-editable-based-on-a-condition/55842169#55842169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. 
I had to use disabled in inputText for that value.